# How to solve this error "The multi-part identifier" in ado.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I have following query its working fine in SQL Server 2008 but when I connect in ADO.NET, it shows this error:

> The multi-part identifier "v.ClientId" could not be bound.
>   The multi-part identifier "v.ClientId" could not be bound.
>   The multi-part identifier "v.ClientID" could not be bound.
>   The multi-part identifier "v.Fare" could not be bound.
>   The multi-part identifier "v.ClientId" could not be bound.

Query:

```
SELECT
    f.ID, f.ClientID, vc.Name, 
    f.Fare as FixFares, v.Fare as VehicleFare, 
    f.FromPostCode, f.ToPostCode, f.[From], f.[To],
    v.ClientId, v.IsActive, v.VehicleID, vc.ID
FROM
    VehicleFixeFare AS v
INNER JOIN 
    FixFare f ON v.ClientId = f.ClientId 
INNER JOIN
    Vehicle vc ON v.ClientId = vc.ClientId
WHERE
    v.ClientID = 159
```

Code below

```
conn = new SqlConnection(Connection1);
conn.Open();

//  var LIST=(from a in General.GetQueryable<Ve>)
string Query = "select f.ID, f.ClientID, vc.Name, f.Fare as FixFares, v.Fare as VehicleFare, f.FromPostCode, "+
               "f.ToPostCode, f.[From], f.[To], v.ClientId, v.IsActive, v.VehicleID, vc.ID " +  
               "from  VehicleFixeFare as v"+
               "inner join FixFare f on v.ClientId = f.ClientId inner join Vehicle vc on v.ClientId = vc.ClientId where v.ClientID =" + ClientID;

SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, conn);
dt = new DataTable();

ad.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: If you look at your string you should notice that there is no space between the alias of the `VehicleFixeFare as v` and the `inner join`.  Also I would also suggest changing the query to prevent potential sql injection attacks, if the clientID is freetype or can manipulated in some way by the user it could be potentially dangerous. Look to change this to a parameter.

Comment: Create a stored  procedure. At the very least, ClientID should be made a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the space issue. Leave some space in the starting and ending of each line, your issue will be resolved.

```
string Query = " select f.ID, f.ClientID, vc.Name, f.Fare as FixFares, v.Fare       as VehicleFare, f.FromPostCode, "+
           " f.ToPostCode, f.[From], f.[To], v.ClientId, v.IsActive, v.VehicleID, vc.ID " +  
           " from  VehicleFixeFare as v "+
           " inner join FixFare f on v.ClientId = f.ClientId inner join Vehicle vc on v.ClientId = vc.ClientId where v.ClientID =" + ClientID;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do the code like this, it will eliminate the space issue that is likely the cause of your error and is more readable.

```
string Query = 
        @"select f.ID, f.ClientID, vc.Name, f.Fare as FixFares, v.Fare as VehicleFare, f.FromPostCode, 
                    f.ToPostCode, f.[From], f.[To], v.ClientId, v.IsActive, v.VehicleID, vc.ID 
            from  VehicleFixeFare as v
            inner join FixFare f on v.ClientId = f.ClientId 
            inner join Vehicle vc on v.ClientId = vc.ClientId where v.ClientID =" + ClientID;
```